# jQuery-ui - drag event only on droppable area

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

How can we get drag event of draggable object when it comes on droppable area?
Actually, droppable's over event is not catching drag event of dragging object. Can anyone suggest me for this. Thanks

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
       //console.log(ui.offset); ---------> Works fine
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("#droppable").droppable({
    activeClass: "drop-active",
    hoverClass: "drop-hover",
    accept: "#draggable",
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function (event, ui) {

        $("<div></div>").text(ui.draggable.text()).appendTo(this);

    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        console.log('out');
    },
    over: function (event, ui) {
        var dragItem = ui.draggable;
        var dragOffset = ui.offset;
        //console.log(dragOffset);  ---------> not getting drag events param

    },

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

ok I got your point. You really can't get the actual offset on `over` because it only fires when your drag object enters the droppable. **It only happens once**. We need a workaround for this. This is my solution:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

$("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: true,
    drag: function (event, ui) {
      //here it works fine 
      //console.log(ui.offset);
      x = ui.offset.left;
      y = ui.offset.top;
      console.log(x + " " + y);
    }
});
```

and in your `over` event:

```
over: function (event, ui) {
        var dragOffsetx = x;
        var dragOffsety = y;
    }
```

I created a global variable [x and y] and update it on `drag`. But you can still get the value on `over` event because it is declared globally.

Comment: it is not giving me offset postion of draggable helper over dropping area.

Comment: It seems that I dont get your question correctly. What exactly are you trying to acheive here?

Comment: Hi, I am looking for to get drag position of draggable object on droppable area like it gets in draggable's drag method.

Comment: By drag position, you mean its x and y coordinates within the screen? Isn't `ui.offset` exactly gives you that?

Comment: It's not getting continuously as we move object overs on droppable area like our drag event gives it.

Comment: Cant replicate. `ui.offset.left` and `ui.offset.top` works for me on both `drag` and `over` events. Can you post it on fiddle with replicated bugs?